# Why is realloc not resizing the memory of my array?

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc

I'm studying C and I'm seeing something that it's not clear to me.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("I'm using malloc\n");
    int  size = 10000000;
    int *arr  = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("memory could not be allocated\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    printf("Check the memory of the process\n");
    int c;
    scanf("%d", &c);
    printf("I'm using realloc\n");
    int *newArr = realloc(arr, 5 * sizeof(int));
    if (newArr == NULL) {
        printf("memory could not be allocated\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int d;
    printf("Check the memory of the process\n");
    scanf("%d", &d);
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    free(newArr);
}
```

If I check the process running with top, I can see that the memory of the process shrinks because of the `realloc` operation, what I wasn't expecting is that the last `for` loop is actually printing the first 15 numbers from `arr`. I was expecting an error due to missing elements from 5 to 15.

```
I'm using malloc
Check the memory of the process
45
I'm using realloc
Check the memory of the process
45
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Can you explain to me how this is working?

Comment: The memory had not yet been recycled / reused.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was that but I wanted to be sure because I saw it being freed on the process monitor

Answer (score 1):

After the reallocation, you forgot to assign `arr` with `newArr` and then you print values form the invalid `arr`. (UB no 1)

Secondly, even if you assign it (or only change the `arr` to `newArr`) in the `printf` you will access elements outside the array bounds - which is UB no 2